# WSO2 Amazonsns connector issues publishing json message

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to publish a json message using the Amazonsns connector in WSO2 ESB 4.9.  I am able to successfully publish a simple string message however when I set the messagestructure to json in order to send different messages to different platforms and attempting to send json as the value of message it will not work.  I am using a simple transaction that looks almost exactly like the documentation sample.  My Transaction:

```
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
  "region":"us-west-2",
  "accessKeyId":"MyAccessKey",
  "secretAccessKey":"MySecretAccessKey",
  "version":"",
  "messageStructure":"json",
  "subject":"Test",
  "message": {"default":"mess","email":"message"},
  "targetArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:977102061874:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/mobile_iOS_Sandbox/34ed4324e6-1119-67sd-b7dd-f413c88e4e25",
  "topicArn":""
  }
```

My result is an unexpected error sending message out.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,73]Message: Illegal character: <d>
```

My service is also like the example:

```
<amazonsns.init>
        <region>{$ctx:region}</region>
        <accessKeyId>{$ctx:accessKeyId}</accessKeyId>
        <secretAccessKey>{$ctx:secretAccessKey}</secretAccessKey>
        <version>{$ctx:version}</version>
     </amazonsns.init>
     <amazonsns.publish>
        <message>{$ctx:message}</message>
        <subject>{$ctx:subject}</subject>
        <messageStructure>{$ctx:messageStructure}</messageStructure>
        <topicArn>{$ctx:topicArn}</topicArn>
        <targetArn>{$ctx:targetArn}</targetArn>
     </amazonsns.publish>
```

I did not expect much success but just started trying different things....I attempted xml encoding the json message and get the same message on '&'.  Using wire logs I found the content type of the successful messages going to Amazon were application/x-www-form-urlencoded so I also tried url encoding and get same message on the '%'.

I'm running out of ideas.  I double checked the connector documentation to make sure I did not miss anything.  It does say you can use a JSON transaction for Publish and gives a sample transaction however it does not discuss anything special/different that you would need to set up in order to make this work.  Is there something I am missing?

UPDATE: Can see it is using the Builder for application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is stumbling on the json.  Have tried setting messageType and ContentType properties to application/json.  JSON Builder is enabled.  It just seems the connector wants to send it out as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, is there something I am not setting properly to tell the connector this is JSON?

UPDATE: The publish template that comes with the connector is setting the messagetype to applicaiton/x-www-form-urlencoded which is overriding any of the settings I am making in my proxy service.  Going to look at changing the template in the connector to use a different messagetype and/or allow me to set it in the proxy dynamically then will be trying again.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

We have created a public [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBCONNECT-130) for this issue. Please follow that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable message builders for the content types you are sending. make sure following is done.

1. Enable relevent Message builder for each content-type.

   < messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                               class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
2. Make sure Content-Type header property is parsing with the message.
3. Make sure your Json is wellformed.

Comment: Message Builders are enabled. JSON is wellformed. I am not sure how to validate your second point ensuring the Content-Type header is parsing with the message. I have a content type application/json on request, no matter what I do the amazon connector ends up making it application/x-www-form-urlencoded when the transaction exits esb. I have tried properties to set ContentType and messageType.  I can see XFormURLEncodedFormatter as one of the modules in my stacktrace so it looks like it is building the output message with that builder and stumbling on the JSON instead of using the JSON builder.

Comment: Have a set a message builder for application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: I do.  For application/x-www-form-urlencoded org.apache.synapse.commons.formatters.XFormURLEncodedFormatter is the formatter and org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder is the builder.  For application/json org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter is the formatter and org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder is the builder.

Comment: In that case this can be a bug.